# Is there a way to get brands included in the response when getting all the groups using REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently getting the list of all groups that are related to an account using /account/{accountId}/groups and then I would have to iterate through all the groups to get the brands for them which would make my program make as many calls (+1) as there are number of groups and would like to not have to make too many calls to DocuSign.

Is there a way to get brands included in the response for getting all the groups? Something like where you get Recipient tabs included in the Recipients call i.e. GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{templateId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's currently possible to get all groups, including info for all associated brands, in a single API call.  You'll need to do as you describe -- i.e., 1) get all groups, 2) iterate through the collection of groups to retrieve the brand(s) associated with each group.